# Pandas - Return True if value in dfb matches with value in dfa for a particualr row

Tags: python, pandas

I had a requirement, where I had to do an exact match between two columns of two data frames.

```
df[res_name] = df[plain_col] == df[b_col]
```

Now, I am looking to add a **contain** logic to it.

For Example, if

df[b_col] value is found in df[plain_col] then return True, else return False.

Usage

df[b_col] having a value as 1A and df[Plain_col] has a value as 1A12. Then output will be True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need list comprehension with `zip` and `in` for row-wise processing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'plain_col':['1A12','1C12','1B12'],
                   'b_col':['1A','1B','1C']})

df['res_name'] = [b in a for a, b in zip(df['plain_col'], df['b_col'])]
print (df)
  plain_col b_col  res_name
0      1A12    1A      True
1      1C12    1B     False
2      1B12    1C     False
```

**Performance**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'plain_col':['1A12','1C12','1B12'],
                   'b_col':['1A','1B','1C']})

#3k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [15]: %timeit df['res_name'] = [b in a for a, b in zip(df['plain_col'], df['b_col'])]
605 µs ± 30 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit df['res_name'] = df.apply(lambda row:row.b_col in row.plain_col, axis=1)
75.2 ms ± 320 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

EDIT:

Error `argument of type float is not iteratable` obviously mean there are missing values, possible solution is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'plain_col':['1A12','1C12',np.nan],
                   'b_col':['1A','1B','1C']})


def func(a, b):
    if (a != a) or (b != b):
        return False
    return b in a

df['res_name'] = list(map(func, df['plain_col'], df['b_col']))
print (df)
  plain_col b_col  res_name
0      1A12    1A      True
1      1C12    1B     False
2       NaN    1C     False
```

Another more general solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'plain_col':['1A12',6.7,np.nan],
                   'b_col':['1A','1B','1C']})


def func(a, b):
    try:
        return b in a
    except Exception:
        return False

df['res_name'] = list(map(func, df['plain_col'], df['b_col']))
print (df)
  plain_col b_col  res_name
0      1A12    1A      True
1       6.7    1B     False
2       NaN    1C     False
```

Comment: No, I am looking to do it on corresponding row-wise. For example, it would return false for all your examples. 1A is not found in plain_col index 0 and 1B is not found in plain_col index1 and 1C is not found in plain_col index 2.

Comment: @Sid29 - Change solution.

Comment: It says, argument of type float is not iteratable.

Comment: @Sid29 - I was worried about it, give me some time

Comment: @Jezarel - This logic works fine, but it fails when both the columns are NaN. It should be returning True, but it returns false. So, how do I tweak the function now..

Comment: @Sid29 So need change `def func(a, b):
    if (a != a) or (b != b):
        return False
    return b in a` to `def func(a, b):
    if (a != a) or (b != b):
        return True
    return b in a`

Comment: Got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
df['res_name'] = df.apply(lambda row:row.b_col in row.plain_col, axis=1)
```

Comment: Possible solution, but slowier in large dataframe.